# How can I simultaneously add information through html form select and input in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, html

I am fetching data from DB Table in form.  I want to automatically select the mobile number of the same customer whose name I select from the list but I am unable to do that because I've to select the mobile number manually. How can I link both enteries?

```
<form> 
<div class="form-group"> 
<label for="customer">Customer Name</label> 
<select class="form-control" name="customer"> 
<option value="">Choose Customer</option> 
<?php foreach ($customers as $key => $customer): ?> 
<option value="{{$customer->id}}">{{$customer->name}} </option> 
<?php endforeach; ?> 
</select> 
</div> 
<div class="form-group"> 
<label for="id">Customer's Mobile</label> 
<?php foreach ($customers as $key => $customer): ?> 
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="customer_mobile" value="{{$customer->mobile}}"> 
<?php endforeach; ?> 
</div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Javascript or any frontend frameworks can be your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a simple `jQuery` snippet can get done this. You may improve this as you wish.

```
   <form>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="customer">Customer Name</label> 
         <select class="form-control" name="customer" id="customer">
            <option value="">Choose Customer</option>
            <?php foreach ($customers as $key => $customer): ?> 
               <option data-mobile-number="{{$customer->mobile}}" value="{{$customer->id}}">{{$customer->name}} </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?> 
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group"> 
         <label for="id">Customer's Mobile</label> 
         <input type="number" class="form-control" name="customer_mobile" value="" id="mobile_number"> 
      </div>
   </form>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#customer").on('change', function(){
            $("#mobile_number").val($(this).find("option:selected").data('mobileNumber'));
         });
      });
   </script>
```

Working JSFiddle demo : https://jsfiddle.net/83oaqfzd/2/

Note : I assume you have included the `jQuery` lib in your project.

Comment: Thank you so much brother. You are a life saver